# How to remove or hide comments on an OxyPlot graph?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, oxyplot

How to remove or hide comments on an [OxyPlot](https://oxyplot.github.io/) graph? I am doing this but it does not work:

```
public void AddAnnotation(IEnumerable<Annotation> annotations)
{
  foreach (var annotation in annotations)
  {
    MyOxyPlotModel.Annotations.Add(annotation);
  }

  RefreshAxisSeriesPlot();
}

public void RemoveAnnotation(IEnumerable<Annotation> annotations)
{
  foreach (var annotation in annotations)
  {
    MyOxyPlotModel.Annotations.Remove(annotation);
  }

  RefreshAxisSeriesPlot();
}

private void RefreshAxisSeriesPlot() => MyOxyPlotModel.InvalidatePlot(true);
```

With this code, adding annotations works, but removing annotations does not work.

**Edit:**

OK, I found the problem in my code.
In fact, I had not completed the evaluation of my LINQ query from which I get my `IEnumerable<Annotation> annotations`… And it recreates a new `Annotation` object at each iteration of `IEnumerable<Annotation> annotations`.

Comment: How are the annotations compared ? Exact same Annotation can be a different object in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably passing in different instances of `Annotation` to your `RemoveAnnotation` method compared to the instances that you have previously added to `MyOxyPlotModel.Annotations`. Passing an instance that doesn't exist in `Annotations` to `Annotations.Remove` won't remove anything since the annotation to be removed cannot be determined.

Make sure that you use the same instances in your `AddAnnotation` and `RemoveAnnotation` methods, or use a property of the annotation to compare it with the existing one.

If you for example use annotations that derive from `TextualAnnotation`, you could compare them by the `Text` property. Something like this:

```
public void RemoveAnnotation(IEnumerable<Annotation> annotations)
{
    foreach (var annotation in annotations)
    {
        if (MyOxyPlotModel.Annotations.Contains(annotation))
            MyOxyPlotModel.Annotations.Remove(annotation);
        else if (annotation is TextualAnnotation ta)
        {
            var existingTa = MyOxyPlotModel.Annotations.OfType<TextualAnnotation>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text == ta.Text);
            if (existingTa != null)
                MyOxyPlotModel.Annotations.Remove(existingTa);
        }
    }

    RefreshAxisSeriesPlot();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You put me on the track.
In fact, I had not completed the evaluation of my LINQ query from which I get my `IEnumerable<Annotation> annotations`… And it recreates a new `Annotation` object at each iteration of `IEnumerable<Annotation> annotations`.